# superclass accesing methods of a sublass in oop

Tags: oop

I was wondering, is it possible that a superclass to access the methods of a inherited subclass, like for example in Java?

I know that a subclass can override and even implements, in case of abstract classes, the methods of the superclass, but the question mentioned above is possible?

Thanks

Comment: You mean downcast an object? yes you can. under some conditions of course.

Comment: yes I think that is correct, can you make an example @riskio?

Comment: I made a complete answer..ask me if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Example in c#.. in superclass make abstract method, which is implemented in derived class

```
public abstract class SuperCLass
{
    public void CallSubMethod()
    {
        Test(); // calls method in derived class
    }
    public abstract void Test();
}

public class SubClas : SuperCLass
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        // code here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, C# (and so on) methods are always *virtual*, so, no matter what, when you override a method in a subclass, this version will be called:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        otherMethod();
    }

    public void otherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public void otherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Sub");
    }
}

SubClass o1 = new SubClass();
o1.someMethod(); // Outputs: Sub 

SuperClass o2 = new SubClass();
o2.someMethod(); // Also outputs: Sub
```

So, you not just CAN access your subclass method, you HAVE TO.

Just for comparison, in C++, for example, things work different. If you don't declare a method as virtual, you can't override it.

Answer (score 0):

I' ll try to explain as they explained to me at university.

You have a reference:

```
Object o = new Object()
```

- His *static type(ST)* is Object : this is his own type and never changes.
- His *dynamic type(DT)* is also Object(in this case): the reference point to an object of type Object, but it can change.

  **for example if i write :**

  ```
  Object o = new String("abc") // now his ST == Object but the DT == String
  ```

That being said:

- Upcasting is always permitted: consider two references *s* and *r*. the assignment s=r compile and execute always if `ST(r) <= ST(s)` (the *static type* of *r* is, in the hierarchi, less or equals to the *static type* of *s*)

  **for example:**

  ```
  class A { }
  class B extends A { }
  ...
  A a = new A(); B b = new B();
  a = b  // OK, upcast
  ```
- Downcasting: at **compile-time** it is always legal to downcast from a type *X* to a type *Y* if *X* and *Y* belong to hierarchy.
  Consider the reference *s*. I want to cast *s* to a type *C*, so if C <= TS(s) it will always compile if I do the cast as :   `C r = (C)s`

  **for example:**

  ```
  class A { }
  class B extends A { }
  class C extends A { }
  ...
  A a = new A(); B b = new B();
  C c = new C();
  ...
  b = c // ILLEGAL
  b = (B)a // OK at compile-time but maybe at run-time it is not!
  ```

  When we run our application if the downcast fails, Java raise an Exception. 
   Otherwise it success.

  **To downcast correctly:**
   consider a reference *ref* and we want to cast to a type *C*. So a downcast will success if `DT(ref) <= C <= ST(ref)` .
   And the downcast will be obtained as: `C ref2 = (C)ref`

  **for example:**

  ```
  // I suggest to write the hierarchy in a piece of paper and 
  // try the rules before coding.

  class A { }
  class B extends A { }
  class C extends A { }
  class D extends B { }
  ...

  A a = new A(); B b = new B();
  C c = new C(); D d = new D();
  A r = new B();
  A s = new D();
  a = b; // OK, upcast
  a = d; // OK, upcast
  /* b = c; */ // ILLEGAL
  b = (B)r; // OK, downcast
  d = (D)r; // downcast: it compiles, but fails at run-time
  d = (D)s; // OK, downcast
  /* b = s; */ // ILLEGAL
  /* d = (D)c; */ // ILLEGAL
  b = (B)s; // OK, downcast
  b = (D)s; // OK, downcast
  ```

PS: please forgive if I made some mistake but I wrote a bit in a hurry.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, It's not possible, and I think what you are asking would go against OOP.