# Is it safe to use static_cast in this polymorphic scenario?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, hierarchy, static-cast

I have a type heirarchy:

```
class Object {
...
};

class Node : public Object {
...
};

class Leaf : public Object {
...
};

class Something : public Node {
...
};

class SomethingElse : public Leaf {
...
};
```

In other words, absolutely every class inherits `Object` either directly or indirectly.

The constructor for every object is in the following format:

```
ClassType(Object * parent)
```

However, by design only a `Node` can be a parent, while a `Leaf` is a terminating node;

In the moment, in every constructor I am doing the following:

```
        Node * p = dynamic_cast<Node *>(parent);
        if (p) p->adopt(this);
        else qDebug() << "for some reason cast failed";
```

So, my primary question is this - considering that every parent object can only be a `Node` or derived from `Node`, is it safe to use `static_cast` instead? Naturally, the primary concern is performance, right now I get about 4 million nodes created per second, which does not seem like a bottleneck, but still, this is barebone hierarchy, as it is populated with more logic it will get slower, so if I can get rid of the `dynamic_cast` it will be a good thing.

I have verified that for `Something s` it will be true that `&s == static_cast<Node *>(&s) == dynamic_cast<Node *>(&s)` but I am not sure whether I can "put all my eggs into that basket" so to speak - is it guaranteed that I can "blindly" reuse the address of every directly or indirectly derived from `Node` class as a `Node *` as long, regardless of whether it is created on the stack, `Object * s = new Something`, `Node * s = new Something`, `Something * s = new Something` or any of the many possible variations?

My secondary question is whether this design is a good idea. I do realize that it is somewhat pointless to pass an `Object *` for parent, considering that only `Node`s can be parents, but the `Node` itself stores its children internally as `Object *` **because not all children derive from `Node`**. Naturally, any recommendations to make this more elegant are welcomed.

Comment: Before you optimize, test and confirm that there's indeed a problem.

Comment: @TonyTheLion - the question is not about performance or optimizations but about whether it is safe to use this or not.

Answer (score 2):

If You are worying about this cast, maybe you should define `parent` member as `Node`? Then You will never need to cast. Also you will be sure you always use Node as a parent.

Answer (score 2):

Now, for some logical reasons you **know** that a parent will always be a `Node`, hence you should use `static_cast`.

Problem is, it's really hard to debug this code if your assumption fails. What you might want to do is something like this:

```
 #ifdef NDEBUG
    Node * p = static_cast<Node*>(parent);
 #else
    Node * p = dynamic_cast<Node *>(parent);
    assert(p);
 #endif
    p->adopt(this);
```

This can be easily achieved with [`boost::polymorphic_downcast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm).

```
 Node * p = boost::polymorphic_downcast<Node*>(parent);
```

Comment: I would actually be able to find exactly where and what is going wrong, because `Object` provides recursive "logging" for the creation and deletion of objects, down to the very data members used. But still this is a good idea, I am even tempted to go for an old dirty macro on this one.

Answer (score 1):

My professor of languages at university told us to avoid as much as possible *dynamic cast* and it is something that I try to do every time I have to develop a complex hierarchy.
That being said, if you know **exactly** that *Parent* points to a *Node* then a *static cast* is safe.

Comment: Replacing `dynamic_cast` whith `static_cast` is *not* the soloution. In generell the use of `dynamic_cast` may inicate bad class desing. The solution is to change the classes.

Comment: Who talked about replacing?

Comment: using `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast` sound form me like replacing it.

Comment: no I did't mean that. I only pointed out that a `static_cast` could be  safely put instead a `dynamic_cast` under certain conditions.

Comment: @riskio Only under **very specific** conditions.

Comment: I wrote those condition in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930128/superclass-accesing-methods-of-a-sublass-in-oop/19933610#19933610

Answer (score 1):

> A pointer to member of some class D can be upcast to a pointer to
>   member of its base class B. This static_cast makes no checks to ensure
>   the member actually exists in the runtime type of the pointed-to
>   object.

In short, if you know that `D` will always be derived from `B`, using `static_cast` is safe.

If performance is one of your concerns, I would suggest simplifying (flatten) your hierarchy.

Comment: The overhead from the dynamic cast turned out to be very minor, it only added like 5% penalty over the rest of the stuff, which is pretty much the dynamic memory allocation and registering the allocated objects in an unoredred hashmap. But still limiting to `Node` in the "parent" context makes it neater and a tiny bit faster, so there is no reason to not keep the modification.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fast (O(1), one virtual call) version for your cast if you create a virtual function which transforms `object` to `node` if it is a node. In case of succes you get a `node*` and in case of a failure you get `nullptr`. This cast is hidden inside the mechanism of the virtual call and thus type safe.

```
class node;
class object {
  // other things
public:
  node const* as_node() const { return 0; }
  node* as_node() { return 0; }
};

class node {
  // other things
public:
  node const* as_node() const { return this; }
  node* as_node() { return this; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* that `parent` is a `Node`, then the `static_cast` does the right thing.

But if you *know* that `parent` is a `Node`, then why not change the constructors (and probably whatever parent pointer you keep inside `Object`) to reflect this reality?

Comment: Yes, storing the parent as a `Node *` might be the way to go, I really wanted to keep the entire hierarchy storage to the bottom base class type, but it doesn't seem like a good idea with the design intent I have in mind.

Comment: I hope I won't run intro trouble down the road due to storing the parent as a `Node` while storing the children as `Object`

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you do downcast (from Object to Node), you have to use `dynamic_cast`. For the other way around (Node to Object), `static_cast` is fine.

The fact that you have to downcast using `dynamic_cast` indicates a problem in design.

I do not know details, but you could change constructors. Instead of taking `Object* parent`, you can take `Node* parent` and `Leaf* parent`.

So, change :

```
struct A
{
  A( Object* parent );
};
```

to :

```
struct A
{
  A( Node* parent );
  A( Leaf* parent );
};
```

also, instead of pointers, I would use references.

---

Another option is to implement the `adopt` method in all classes. In classes that do not need it, will use default no-op operation, and override it in classes that actually do something. Then you do not need to cast.

```
class Object {
  virtual void foo(){ /*no-op*/ }
};

class Node : public Object {
  virtual void foo(){ /* hi-ho */ }
};

class Leaf : public Object {
 // uses default foo
};

void callFoo( Object & obj )
{
  // no need to cast
  obj.foo();
}
```

Comment: `Leaf` cannot be parent, only parented to a `Node`

Comment: @user2341104 it is the parent to SomethingElse

Comment: I think you mistake "parent" as the instance to which an object is parented with BASE CLASS. Only a `Node` class can be a parent, to either `Node` or `Leaf` derived classes. But every `Node` derived class is also an `Object`

Comment: @user2341104 I am not sure I understand your last comment. Are you misusing `Object` as some kind of super-class, as in java?

Comment: `Object` is just the bottom level, the base class for every other object, `Node` and `Leaf` inherit from `Object` and every other object inherits from either `Node` or `Leaf`. But only `Node` has a `List<Object>` member which allows it to be a parent.